# Adding a chat event with invalid date ends in either "website not found" or a JSON response

Tags: bug, chat, events

When I try to create an event for a chat room with an incomplete date the end-result is not what a useability expert would call acceptable.

steps to reproduce:

1. visit your favourite [chatroom schedule event page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers?tab=schedule)
2. in the on field type: `2014/02/9` (notice to leave out the zero)
3. click the <kbd>Add</kbd> button.
4. Be confused...

On IE11/Win7 the result is "Webpage not found"; on Chrome `{"ErrorMessage":"Invalid first date"}`

Can this be fixed so that an error message is shown on the first date field?

Comment: Why can't those have a `jquery-ui` calendar picker anyway...