# How can I set a chatroom event for the new year?

Tags: support, chat, chat-event

I made a new chatroom on ELL.SE and we're going to do *some stuff* there. I need to make an event that'd start in 2016/1/2. However, trying to set the beginning date I get this: `{"ErrorMessage":"Invalid first date"}`

I assume it's because of the "year". It'd be really nice if I wouldn't have to wait two days before creating such an event, since what we're doing is site-wide tag cleaning and two days gone to waste isn't really a good use of our time while we're in a bit of a hurry.

This may be a bug; but still it might be a rate limit to avoid adding nonsensical dates as the beginning dates for chatroom events, IOW making it "idiot-proof", but is it really necessary?

So **how can I set the event to the a day in the next year today?**

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217729/adding-a-chat-event-with-invalid-date-ends-in-either-website-not-found-or-a-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date has to be in this format:

```
2016/01/02
```

I've tested this and it actually works.

However, I do agree that one-digit days and months should be accepted. Those dates are also valid and allowing them would reduce the amount of confusion about why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh darn, why didn't I think of that?